How i can search nested field values in my document? Elasticsearch
i'm using elasticsearch_dsl and i need search by "lastname", this is my doc:
So, can anybody, please provide me with right "query" request to do this.
i'm trying
Q('multi_match', lenient=True, fields=["personal_info.lastname"], query=query, fuzziness='auto')

UPD:
i could do this with:
Q("nested", path="personal_info",
                 query=Q("multi_match", fields=["*"],
                         lenient=True, query=query, fuzziness='auto', ))


edit question and add information from your comment.
